# Do the `else if` really exist in java?

Tags: java

Is the `else if` really exist in java? or it is just an `else` followed by an `if`?

Java will let you type blocks without the brackets if there's just one statement below. Now this means this

```
if(..){

}
else{
   if(...){

   }
}
```

would be the same as this...

```
if(...)

else
    if(...)
```

and if you eat the white space would be

```
if(...)

else if(...)
```

is this correct?

Comment: All three alternatives *could* be exactly the same. As long as there's only a single statement in the body of the `if`.

Comment: @whatamidoingwithmylife this is not my question, I know it works. I'm asking if the `else if` exist or it is just a combined `else` and `if`

Comment: It *is* a parser rule in Java and C-like languages.

Comment: there is no "special" `elseif` like php has. the `if` is the statement that is executed in the `else` case.

Comment: Why is this an important detail?  Syntactic sugar has existed in languages for quite some time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have a look at the grammar [in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html):

```
Statement:
    [...]
    if ParExpression Statement [else Statement] 
    [...]
```

`else if` will in other words just be parsed as `else` followed by a new `if` statement, and not together as a unit.

Comment: thanks, this is what I thought, but had no one to confirm.